# Adjusting flexbox grid for large and small screen sizes

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I did two layouts.

First one is for medium & large screens, the last one is for max-width 736px device resolution.

[**Here is vanilla implementation with flexbox**](https://jsfiddle.net/ufvcL4rc/2/) (without mobile adaptation)

[**And here is with bootstrap**](https://jsfiddle.net/7jugkw4p/), I can then merge, because it is using flexboxes also

[image]

```
<div class="d-flex gutters">
    <div class="bigger-cell">
        <div class="hero">
            I'm Hero!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="hero">
            I'm Hero!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex gutters">
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="hero">
            I'm Hero!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="hero">
            I'm Hero!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="hero">
            I'm Hero!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use order property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layouts you want (both large and small screens) can be achieved efficiently with flexbox.

Your code can be simplified substantially.

https://jsfiddle.net/kmsxpk3q/

```css
html, body {
  background: linear-gradient(#ade3e8, #b4b4b4) no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.d-flex>div {
  margin: 5px;
}

.hero {
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 10px);
  padding: 30px 0;
  background: #7e58b7;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.hero:first-child {
  flex-basis: calc(66.66% - 10px);
}

@media (max-width: 736px) {
  .hero {
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 10px);
  }
  .hero:first-child {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="hero">I'm Hero!</div>
  <div class="hero">I'm Hero!</div>
  <div class="hero">I'm Hero!</div>
  <div class="hero">I'm Hero!</div>
  <div class="hero">I'm Hero!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Guess that this question is for the new topic, but still, can you please check, why bigger rectangle has less img-height relatively to his smaller square https://jsfiddle.net/ufvcL4rc/3/

Comment: It's because you're using a different image with a different aspect ratio. To workaround the problem, use `width: 100%` / `height: 100%`, instead of `max-width` / `max-height`: https://jsfiddle.net/ufvcL4rc/4/